# Not able to feed categorical variable to Random Forest

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, random-forest

I have 10 categorical variable and 3 numerical variable.I directly fed them to Random Forest after the split but it shows,

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'No internet service'
```

I read that Random Forest can handle both numeric and categorical variable.Why is this showing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the library that you are using for implementing RandomForest. For example, R can handle categorical variables with RandomForest. However from my experience so far Sci-kit in Python requires conversion to dummy variables. The error tells me that you are using Python, so you would most likely be using sklearn, which requires conversion to dummy variables. You can convert your column with one line of code.

```
pd.get_dummies(df['column_name'])
```

Comment: Thanks.Yes iam using scikit learn.When I used get dummies it works well.

Comment: Got it.Thanks bro